# TypeError: discord_js_1.Intents is not a constructor after making a timeout command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, typeerror

so I was coding the timeout command and when I wanted to try it out I got the following error

```
/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/distube/dist/util.js:90
    const intents = new discord_js_1.Intents(bitfield);
                    ^

TypeError: discord_js_1.Intents is not a constructor
    at checkIntents (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/distube/dist/util.js:90:21)
    at new DisTube (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/distube/dist/DisTube.js:44:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Structures/index.js:30:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Before even having the timeout command and when I made the timeout command I suddenly got this error.

Here is my timeout code:

```
const { CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "timeout",
    description: "Timeout a member.",
    options: [
        {
            name: "user",
            description: "Member to perform the timeout on",
            type: "USER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "length",
            description: "Length of the timeout.",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "Reason for this timeout.",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true
        }
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction){
        const user = interaction.options.getUser("user")
        const length = interaction.options.getString("length")
        const reason = interaction.options.getString("reason")
        const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)

        const timeInMs = ms(length);
        if(!timeinMs) return interaction.followUp("Please specify a valid time!");

        member.timeout(timeInMs, reason)
        interaction.followUp(`${user} has been timeouted for ${length}! (${reason})`)

    }
};
```

Here is the code where the client is defined

```
const {Client,Collection} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({intents: 32767});
const {token} = require('./config.json');

const {promisify} = require("util");
const {glob} = require("glob");
const PG = promisify(glob);
const Ascii = require("ascii-table");

client.commands = new Collection();

const {DisTube} = require("distube");
const {SpotifyPlugin} = require("@distube/spotify");

client.distube = new DisTube(client, {
    emitNewSongOnly: true,
    leaveOnFinish: true,
    emitAddSongWhenCreatingQueue: false,
    plugins: [new SpotifyPlugin()]
});
module.exports = client;

require("../Systems/GiveawaySys")(client);

["Events", "Commands"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./Handlers/${handler}`)(client, PG, Ascii);
});

client.login(token);
```

I don't know why I am suddenly getting this error, could someone help me with this?

Comment: The error relates to the usage of *Intents*, you will most likely find the source of the error in the place you defined your client. Can you show how your client is defined

Comment: Yes, here you go https://sourceb.in/L5Dspw1jnV

Comment: I added the file where the client is defined into the question

Comment: Please make sure to include the full error stack in your question, as there is no place in the code you showed that uses `Intents` (not `intents`)

Comment: I added the full error in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be the result of a dependency incompatibility. It is possible that a module you installed requires a specific version of Discord.js, but your using an unsupported Discord.js version. Or the module is outdated and you need to update it using `npm outdated` then `npm update`

The error stack doesn't reference the file where you are writing the command's code.. unless you've placed the file in node_modules. So the error isn't from the command file, but rather your modules.

I think that the module that's malfunctioning is called distube. Take a look at their [module requirements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/distube) and make sure the other modules in your project meet the requirements, or uninstall the module by running `npm uninstall distube`

Comment: Thank you so much, the module was outdated